# Change color of button bar in date picker dialog

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to change the button bar in the date picker dialog? Really can't figure it out. I want the white to be black. Thanks

```
     <style name="DarkDateDialog" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">?attr/background_1</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/background_1</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">?attr/background_1</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. you just use a light theme!

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

in this example the accent color is the header and the body will be white .